# Plotting multiple time series in BIRT

Tags: birt

As a new Birt user I am now facing the challenge: I have a set of temperature measurements T1 T2 T3 and T4. The data is like *T1: [(datetime1, temperature1), (datetime2, temperature2), ...], T2: ...* and so on. I want to have x-axis as time and y-axis as degrees, and plot 4 curves corresponding temperature measurements.

The questions are
1. Is it possible to combine all datetimes of the four data sets into a single x-axis?
2. Is Birt capable of drawing such curves, if there are thousands of temperature samples to be squeezed into?

Thanks for your helpful answers.

Comment: It should be possible. What data source are you using (relational DB / other), and how is the data structured?

Comment: @MarkBannister I am using a CSV file as data source. The data is generated, so its structure is really flexible. Now it's stored like T1_measured_time, T1, T2_measured_time, T2,...